# os.path.isfile fails when using sys.path.append

Tags: python-3.x, path

I have the following:

```
application/3rdPArtyApp/file.py
application/3rdPArtyApp/directory/someFile
application/MyApp/file.py
```

I want to access files from 3rdPArtyApp from MyApp so I do the following in MyApp/file.py

```
sys.path.append('../3rdPArtyApp')
```

This works fine and I can now access the files and functions by importing them.
However, there is a file in 3rdPartyApp that attempts to access a file inside a folder **directory/someFile**.

It uses the following to check if its a file which **fails** whenever its called from MyApp but doesn't fail when its called stand alone from 3rdPartyApp.

```
os.path.isfile(file)
```

I am assuming if fails when called from MyApp because its expecting it to beunder MyApp path.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, it fails because it is a relative path, and your current working directory is different than 3rdPartyApp expects. If you have access to the app, you could change the `os.path.isfile(file)` to a path relative to `__file__`. Otherwise, there isn't a lot you can do, except of running changing the working directory to the 3rdPartyApp folder, which (i guess) is not what you want.

Comment: Also: Don't name a variable `file`, it is a python keyword.

Comment: I cannot change the 3rdPArtyApp code unfortunately.  Is there a way I can change the working directory to 3rdPArtyApp when I use functions from it??

Comment: Yes. Give me a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot change the library code, I think you are stuck with having to change the working directory before every call.

I therefore implemented this function-like helper class `change_cwd`. Just wrap every function call to the external library with `with change_cwd('../3rdPArtyApp'):`.

```
import os

class change_cwd:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = os.path.abspath(path)
    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_cwd = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(self.path)
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        os.chdir(self.old_cwd)

print(os.getcwd())
with change_cwd('Downloads'):
    print(os.getcwd())
print(os.getcwd())
```

```
/home/<user>
/home/<user>/Downloads
/home/<user>
```

Comment: This is your world and I'm just glad you let me live in it ;)